# Custom Jquery Slideshow Won't Move To The Correct Slide

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm creating an auto_play loop function to have slides slide infenitly.
But I'm having problems when the variable slidePosition is equal to 1 the if function that validates that won't trigger.

html

```
<div class="slide_wrap">
    <div class="slides">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="images/img_01.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/img_02.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/img_03.jpg"/></li>
      </ul>
</div></div>
```

js

```
$(".slides").bind("auto_play.loop", function(){
if(slidePosition == 1){<br/>
$(this).delay(1000).animate({right:'+='+slideWidth, easing: 'swing'}, 1000);<br/>
slidePosition = 2;<br/>
        }<br/>
        if(slidePosition == 2){<br/>
            $(this).delay(1000).animate({right:'+='+slideWidth, easing: 'swing'}, 1000);<br/>
            slidePosition = 3;<br/>
        }<br/>
        if(slidePosition == 3){<br/>
            $(this).delay(1000).animate({right:'-='+2*slideWidth, easing: 'swing'}, 1000);<br/>
            slidePosition = 1;<br/>
        }<br/>
        trigger("auto_play.loop");<br/>
    }).trigger("auto_play.loop");
```

Comment: do my mind posting some html or possibly creating a small demo on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: If you could get your stuff working on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that would be a huge help. Meantime, im working on it.

Comment: never used this site but will try my best to bring the code to it

Comment: so far got this from jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/KK3rV/

Comment: Cool still working on it :D but that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I think your issue was your if statements.  Inside each you would need to call and else if, otherwise the slidenumber would be set and the next if statement would run.

After reviewing the code I understand what your trying to accomplish took your approach and cleaned it up a little. Instead of calling jquery triggers I moved those into method calls.  Now after each animation is completed it will call the Update function to get the next animation in the sequence, much cleaner and easier to maintain.

There are still things that need cleaned up. Such as making it take an infinite amount of slides. Right now its hard coded to only do three. While that works it would be good to abstract out the count, and have it read the dom and get a count that way.

You can view the solution on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qrs6/)

**Update:**
Modified the javascript to take an unlimited amount of slides. I suggest you use this type of approach so you can keep adding slides and never touch an ounce of javascript.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFDQu/)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      //On page load initialize the slideshow
                      MyApp.SlideShow.init();
                  });
//create a namespace for our code
var MyApp = MyApp || {};

//create a function inside a closure to handle all slideshow functions
MyApp.SlideShow = (function ()
{
    var slidePosition = 1;
    var slideWidth = 100;
    var slider = $('.slides');     

    //called when page is loaded
    function init()
    {
        var v = $('.viewer');      
        var vtop = v.position().top;
        vleft = v.position().left;    
        //Set the slider to where the view is 
        slider.css('left', vleft).css('top', vtop);
        update();
    };

    //function to update the slide block
    function update()
    {
        if (slidePosition == 1) {
            slider.delay(1000).animate({
                left: '-=' + slideWidth,
                easing: 'swing'
            }, 1000, update);
            slidePosition = 2;
        }
        else if (slidePosition == 2) {
            slider.delay(1000).animate({
                left: '-='+ slideWidth,
                easing: 'swing'
            }, 1000, update);
            slidePosition = 3;
        }
        else if (slidePosition == 3) {
            slider.delay(1000).animate({
                left: '+=' + 2 * slideWidth,
                easing: 'swing'
            }, 1000, update);
            slidePosition = 1;
        }
    };    
    return {
        init: init
    };
}());
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slide_wrap">
    <div class="slides">
      <ul>
        <li class="s1">1</li>
        <li class="s2">2</li>
        <li class="s3">3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="viewer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.viewer
{
    border:5px solid yellow;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:300px;
}
.slides li
{    
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
float:left;
}
.slides ul
{    
  height:100px;
}
.slides
{
    position:absolute;
}
.s1
{
  background-color:red;  
}
.s2
{
  background-color:blue;  
}
.s3
{
  background-color:green;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much cgatian for your time and patience. I tried to embed the code you created but I just started learning jquery two days ago and I think it is too advanced for me because I keep receiving errors when I try to load it. Meanwhile I started exploring the site JSFIDDLE and uploaded all my code to there.
I have been the last two days constructing this slider app and the only thing I need to finish is for it to slide automatically from the position it was navigated to. If you could see what am I doing wrong here it would be a huge help for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/circle73/m2UbV/

Comment: Answer accepted :) Did you have the oportunity to see?jsfiddle.net/circle73/m2UbV

Comment: You are looking for the slide show to advance when the little gray bar at the bottom completes?

Comment: Yes exactly, I tried to make the auto play inside the function that animates the grey bar to slide when it reaches 940 pixels but it crashed the whole app

Comment: I encountered another bug, when the animation is in the middle of the transition to the next slide and you hover the mouse for it to pause, it memorizes the position and then never finishes the transition making the whole carrousel crash. Is there a way for the animation to ignore the hover function when it is on the middle of a transition?

Comment: The code needs abstracted and triggers and delays removed. Utilize functions instead of triggers. Theres a lot of bugs your going to uncover the way it's currently designed. http://jsfiddle.net/zPkFp/